# Non-zero coefficients of primitive polynomials

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $R$ be a finite field of $q$ elements, $m,n\in \mathbb{N}, 2\leq m, 2\leq n$. I want to prove that there exists a primitive polynomial $$F(x) = x^{mn}-\sum\limits_{j=0}^{mn-1}f_jx^j\in R[x]$$
with the following property. There exists $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that $f_{km}\neq 0$.
I think that it is always true, except the case, when $q=m=n=2$.

Comment: It may, indeed, be that $m=n=q=2$ is the only exception. The shear number of primitive polynomials makes this more likely in bigger cases (when we have more than two primitive polynomials to choose from). Admittedly I didn't check the probabilities. A cool question! I don't see a promising approach, at least not right away.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how to "attack" this problem for about a week)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post here a Hansen-Mullen's conjecture, which was proved in 2007. The validity of my assumption in the question is a straightforward consequence of this conjecture.

**Conjecture**.(Hansen and Mullen, 1992)
*Let $a\in \mathbb{F}_q$ and let $n\geq2$ be a positive integer. Fix and integer $m$ with $0<m<n$. Then there exists a primitive polynomial $f(x) = x^n
+\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_jx^{n-j}$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $a_m = a$ with (genuine) exceptions when*
$$
(q,n,m,a) = (q,2,1,0), (4,3,1,0), (4,3,2,0), (2,4,2,1).
$$
The proof is carried out in several stages. See for details Stephen D Cohen,  [Primitive polynomials with a prescribed coefficient](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1071579705000663), Finite Fields and Their Applications 12 (2006) 425-491. The completion of the proof is given in Cohen and Presern, The Hansen-Mullen primitivity conjecture: completion of proof, in McKee and Smyth, eds.,  [Number Theory and Polynomials](http://www.cambridge.org/ru/academic/subjects/mathematics/number-theory/number-theory-and-polynomials), London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series 352.